# signing in youtube without other google service

Tags: youtube, android-tv

I have android tv box and wants to access my youtube subscription. 
is there any way to just login youtube without the rest of google service? I dont want to see email pop up when watching videos... of cos, i wont want to have hangout chat on my tv.. etc

Answer (score 0):

If your device is indeed an Android TV box, it won't show email notifications, or any sort of notifications while in use.

Comment: actually, it is android box not android tv.